# JavaScript HTML element to DOM selector

Tags: javascript

I have a function that requires a HTML element to perform the action on. I request the DOM selector as a parameter

`function(document.body);`

where element is the DOM query but somewhere else in the function I need the query as a string. Is it possible to turn the object into it's original string type? And if so, how?

Comment: Do you have an example of the expected result?

Comment: What do you mean by "the original string type"? `body` is a DOM element, and has no string type, original or otherwise. What are you planning to do with this string?

Comment: The problem is, a single DOM element might have several possible query strings that will return it uniquely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the other way around. Pass your function a selector string:

```
functionName('body')
```

And then retrieve the relevant DOM element using [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
var el = document.querySelector(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are using is not going to produce the right results consistently in my opinion.

Passing in the element is going to mean that the element must be found beforehand and also is going to practically prevent finding other elements of similar location due to a lack of information.

Passing in a selector is an option, and then using that going forward if you need to find a similar set of elements but sometimes the selector is too complex to be placed in one string - for example if it needs filtering or some other metric.

Your best bet is to accept a callback function that returns the desired element or set of elements when you are dealing with complex selectors or locations for elements. It can simply return the same element each time if it is basic, or if it is more complicated the callback can access the DOM, filter based on some metric, and then return the subset which at times is ideal.

A callback function will provide the full amount of support without needing to always have a conversion to query string which is not always possible for complex structures.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you could to this

```
function (elem) {
  if (typeof elem === 'string' || elem instanceof String) {
    elem = document.querySelector(elem);    
  }

  var target = elem.querySelector(...);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the HTML string of an element use 'innerHTML'.

Temporary parent:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
```

Append desired element to parent:

```
div.appendChild(document.body);
```

Test result:

```
alert(div.innerHTML);
```

If you are trying to get the string of the resulting element of 'querySelector()':

```
div.appendChild(document.body.querySelector('yourClass'));
```

The temporary parent ensures that you get the tags for the element returned. Otherwise you would only get the string for its child elements. If you want to use 'querySelectorAll()', just loop over the returned node array.

Comment: This is not what's asked for

Comment: It seems to me that he wants to pass in an object, manipulate it, and then be able to do something with the resulting HTML string. If you know what is being asked for, why did you not answer?